# How to set WRITE_TRUNCATE from BigQuery PHP SDK?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs) suggests to set:

`configuration.load.writeDisposition` to `WRITE_TRUNCATE`.

However, when attempting to set the option for this, nothing works. The following array consists of all the options I've tried:

```
    $options = [
        'configuration.load.writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        'configuration.writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        'writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        'configuration' => [
            'writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            'load' => [
                'writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $table->load($data, $options);
```

I added each option individually, observing each time that the table merely grew in size.

Comment: Could be a bug in the library. Mind filing an issue at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php ?

Comment: @TimSwast duly filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues/622

Comment: And a pull request is now in that fixes the issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/pull/623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/pull/623) that fixes the issue I can now confirm the correct way to define this option is as follows:

```
    $options = [
        'configuration' => [
            'load' => ['writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE']
        ],
    ];
```